# Refreshing the frame of my UICollectionView's header

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this issue where upon removing a cell from my collection view, the header's y origin will be offset by the same amount that the removed cell's offset scrolled off the screen. So the header will drop down about 1-55 points depending on how much of the last cell is showing (my cells heights are 55 points each).

However, as soon as I scroll the collectionView, the header will return to exactly how it should be.

Is there a way to programmatically update my collection View's frame to exactly what it should be in relation to the collection views scroll offest? Or just refresh its frame correctly, somehow scrolling sets the frame correctly.

OR perhaps i need to refresh my collectonview subviews? NOT SURE

Thanks for any help.

Comment: why not try updating the frame of your header view (assuming it is programmatically created) change the y value to origin.y - 55? In whatever method you have where the cell disappears

Comment: Yeah I tried this, and it works, but It doesn't solve the problem for when the cell is 54 off, 53... 22..11... etc. I'm trying to think of a way to create a function to return the offset. But again, this feels really hacky. There has to be a better way. @kylecman

Comment: I see. Did you set anything to the UICollectionViewFlowLayout? I don't use collection views often but I know that has been a thing I forgot in the past. @Andy

Comment: I'm using a custom stickyHeaderFlowLayout. CSStickeyHeaderFlowLayout. The header is parallax. @kylecman

Comment: Oh wow that's a nice looking custom layout! I would submit an issue on github. That is beyond my reach lol